# Join 2 tables, add first table as column headers for datagridview then add second table as rows below column headers

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datatable, datagridview, inner-join

I want to add columns for FACILITIES and then use their **fac_id** to find the their water production from another table to be displayed as a single row below the column headers.

```
Do While tableRetrieve.Read = True

table.Columns.Add(tableRetrieve("facility"), Type.GetType("System.String"))

Dim newDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dtpFrom.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s tt",
  System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
Dim myDate As String = newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

If myDate = tableRetrieve("sentDate") Then

If tableRetrieve("prod_id") = tableRetrieve("fac_id") Then
table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("facility_produce"))
End If

End If

Loop
```

I can add the column headers but failed in rows.

Below is an image of the output. Column headers are displayed but the water production quantities are only displayed in one row. There should be water production quantities for each corresponding columns based on **prod_id** equals **fac_id**.

[Sample of DataGridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqhJ1.png)

**UPDATE:**

This is what my code looks like now. This works well if there's only one row. the errors display if there's another row.

```js
Do While tableRetrieve.Read = True

  table.Columns.Add(tableRetrieve("facility"), Type.GetType("System.String"))

  If tableRetrieve("facility_id") = tableRetrieve("fac_id") Then

    newDate = tableRetrieve("sentDate")

    If prevDate = newDate Then

    table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
    prevDate = newDate
    col += 1

    Else

    If row = 0 Then
    col += 1
    table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("sentDate"))
    table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
    prevDate = newDate
    col += 1
    Else
    col = 0
    row += 1
    table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("sentDate"))
    table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
    col += 1
    End If

    End If

  End If

Loop

dgvFacility.DataSource = table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each loop you write `tableRetrieve("facility_produce")` in new row. You should write it to next column instead.

```
Dim col As Integer = 0    
Do While tableRetrieve.Read = True

table.Columns.Add(tableRetrieve("facility"), Type.GetType("System.String"))

Dim newDate As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dtpFrom.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy h:m:s tt",
  System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
Dim myDate As String = newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

If myDate = tableRetrieve("sentDate") Then

If tableRetrieve("prod_id") = tableRetrieve("fac_id") Then
  If col = 0 Then
     table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("facility_produce"))
  Else
     table.Rows(0)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
  End If
  col += 1
End If

End If

Loop
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm! I didn't know you could code table.rows like that. So much searching in google and there's no sample code like that. You're a genius! :)

Comment: I tried adding rows for new values but I get an error that column 1 or 2 or 3 is not found. :( I also get an error for a duplicate name of column.

Comment: You should add columns (table.Columns.Add...) only when proseccing the first row, then columns are ready for all rows.

Comment: I did inner join and I can only add columns after the Do while tableRetrieve.Read = True. Is there any way I can add the columns even if tables were inner joined?

Comment: I also get an error System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find column 2.' when I try to add an if statement to check if column name exists.

Comment: How to do that? Just post here in comment or as answer? :(

Comment: Already updated my question with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

First things first. I added `Dim countColumns As Integer` in the beginning of the form to be called later to count columns.

I inserted `countColumns += 1` in the part where I display a blank row datagridview but with column headers in it. There the columns that are registered in the database are already counted. So I can use it later to call the number of columns.

I then placed `table.Columns.Count <= countColumns` so the column count increases as the columns are displayed and then stop adding columns once the number of columns registered in the database are equal, to avoid errors on duplication.

This is the part of my program where I display the columnd headers and the row values:

```js
Try
SQLConnection.Open()
tableRetrieve = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader

table.Columns.Add("Date", Type.GetType("System.String"))

Do While tableRetrieve.Read = True

    If table.Columns.Count <= countColumns Then

        table.Columns.Add(tableRetrieve("facility"), Type.GetType("System.String"))

    End If

    newDate = tableRetrieve("sentDate")


    If prevDate = newDate Then

        table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
        prevDate = newDate
        col += 1

    Else

        If col = 0 Then

            col += 1
            table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("sentDate"))
            table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
            prevDate = newDate
            col += 1

        Else

            col = 1
            row += 1
            table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("sentDate"))
            table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
            prevDate = newDate
            col += 1

        End If

    End If

Loop

dgvFacility.DataSource = table
tableRetrieve.Close()
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As MySqlException
MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
Finally
SQLConnection.Close()
End Try
```

This part of the program checks if the dates are the same by this code: `prevDate = newDate`, if they are the same then the program will add the **facility_produce** on the same row by the corresponding column. If date not the same then the program checks if **col** is zero, if zero then the datagridview is still empty and the program will input the first row with its amount produced. And if **col** is not zero, it means there's already a **new date** and that there's already an existing row then the program has to input the next row of values below.

```js
If prevDate = newDate Then

    table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
    prevDate = newDate
    col += 1

Else

    If col = 0 Then

        col += 1
        table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("sentDate"))
        table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
        prevDate = newDate
        col += 1

    Else

        col = 1
        row += 1
        table.Rows.Add(tableRetrieve("sentDate"))
        table.Rows(row)(col) = tableRetrieve("facility_produce")
        prevDate = newDate
        col += 1

    End If

End If
```

Sorry for the long post, but I hope this will help and guide anyone who is using inner join and then use the row values as column headers. I had a hard time solving this. Haven't used VB programming since 2010. I was still using VB 6 way back 2010 and I am very outdated with VB.Net now. Have a lot to learn and I am enjoying it.

Thank you @milda for the help. Your code guided me in placing my values in their right positions.

Comment: Oh yeah, you got it yourself! That's the best way to learn it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Hope my code here also helps other coders. :)